# convert a 64bit stream to array list in java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement DES code in java. I have bit stream of 64bits that I required to change it to ArrayList of Integer type.
I am able to convert it to an array as shown below.

```
public class strtoArr {
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String string = "0100010111010001000011110111110100010110110011001010001101010010";
        final char[] ch=string.toCharArray();
        for (final char chh: ch ) {
            System.out.print(chh);
        }
    }
}
```

I want an Arraylist of integer type so that I can access each element index wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just :

```
String string = "0100010111010001000011110111110100010110110011001010001101010010";
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(string.charAt(i))));
}
```

Here we create a list of type `Integer` and then iterate over each character of the string and parse it to an int.

Comment: This solved my purpose. The code is brief and concise. Tk @Nicholas K.

Answer (score 0):

Approach using stream API.

```
Arrays.stream(str.split(“”))
      .map(Integer::valueOf)
      .collect(toList());
```

or Pattern API:

```
Pattern.compile(“”)
       .splitAsStream(str)
       .map(Integer::valueOf)
       .collect(toList());
```